# ruby remove common element collections

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three classes: User, Subscription and Plan. I want to load all of the Plans that the User doesn't have. What's the best way to do it in Rails?

I have two collections: `current_user.subscriptions` and `Plan.where(active: true)`
And i am using mongoid

```
def dashboard
  @plans = Plan.where(active: true)#.each { @plans.delete_if has_current_user_plan      subscription.title }
end

def has_current_user_plan(name)
  current_user.subscriptions.where(title: name, active: true).exists?
end
```

```
class User
  has_many :subscriptions
```

```
class Subscription
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user
```

```
class Plan
  has_many :subscriptions
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AR:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :plans, through: :subscriptions # !!!
end

Plan.where(active: true).where.not(id: current_user.plans)
```

I'm not really sure what's the best approach for Mongoid because I've never used it. From what I've gather from the documentation, something like the following might work although I'm not running the code.

```
Plan.where(active: true).not_in(_id: Subscription.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:plan_id))
```

Comment: Thanks, actualy I am using MongoID; so I can't do that. any other idea?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The approach is the same, gather the user's plan ids and then select every plan whose id doesn't match.

Comment: ok, thanks; I will check and let you know because I am having issue with the paypal sandbox right now :(, I can't complete the subscription process to tell you if it is working fine; but at least it compile ok.

Comment: It working :) thank you. one more thing, where did you get the documentation? I was looking around for it, please paste the link.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. I was looking at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/querying.html and digging through the source codes at https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid. Github's repo search is pretty neat.